# Как мне сделать функцию для добавления элемент в заданую позицию односвязного списка?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>

class List // класс список
{

public:

    List(); // конструктор
    ~List(); // деструктор

    void push_back(T data); // вставить в конец списка 
    int GetSize() { return Size; } 
    T& operator[](const int index); 
    void add(Node<T> *head, int pos, int x);
    void print(Node *top);

private:

    template<typename T> 

    class Node // класс "Узел"
    {

    public:
        Node *pNext; // указатель на следующий элемент
        T data; // данные
        int x;

        Node(T data = T(), Node *pNext = nullptr) // по умолчанию пусто
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }

    };

    Node<T> *head; // голова
    int Size;  // для хранения количества элементов 

};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;

}

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{

}

template<typename T>
inline void List<T>::push_back(T data) 
{
    if (head == nullptr) // если голова пустая 
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data); // создаём голову 

    }
    else { // если нет

        Node<T> * current = this->head; // создаём времменая переменная с указателем на current и присваиваем ей значение заголовка
        while (current->pNext != nullptr) // поиск следующего элемента. Если сдедующий элемент не пуст 
        {
            current = current->pNext; // присваевания указателя на следующий елемент  
        }

        current->pNext = new Node<T>(data); // создаём следующий элмент 
    }
    Size++;
}

template<typename T>
inline T & List<T>::operator[](const int index) // перегрузка оператора []
{
    int counter = 0; // счётчик 

    Node<T> *current = this->head;

    while (current != nullptr) // если следующий элемент не пустой
    {
        if (counter == index) // проверка на совпадения 
        {
            return current->data; // возвращаем данные
        }
        current = current->pNext; // указатель на следующий элемент 
        counter++; // счётчик + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавить новый **node** на месте **next** с хвостом бывшего **next**-а. Примерно так: list.push_newnode_to_next(list[index-1],pos,x)

Answer (score 0):

Гуглиться за 1 минуту. В интеррнете куча информации на этот счет.
http://www.intuit.ru/studies/professional_skill_improvements/2056/courses/504/lecture/11456?page=2